# No output for $ grep '[^a-z]\{22\}' /usr/share/dict/words

Tags: shell, grep, regular-expression

After executing

```
grep '[a-z]\{22\}' /usr/share/dict/words
```

the output is

```
counterrevolutionaries
electroencephalographs
```

but while executing

```
grep '[^a-z]\{22\}' /usr/share/dict/words
```

there is not output.

I was expecting that it will generate similar results as that of

```
grep -v '[a-z]\{22\}' /usr/share/dict/words
```

My question is what's wrong and why ?

Comment: It might help an Answerer if you described your current understanding of `[^a-z]` and `grep -v`.

Comment: @JeffSchaller [^a-z] not to match any one in the range and grep -v means that it will show non-matching lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[specification]` matches a collating element (can be a character or sequence of characters as defined in the collating algorithm for the locale (for instance, in Hungarian locales on GNU systems, `dzs` is a collating element that sorts somewhere between `d` and `e`)) in the *specified* set.

That specification can include

- ranges like `a-z` (or `[.dzs.]-z`) for collating elements that collate between `a` and `z` (note that it  generally includes abcdefghijklmnoprstuvwxyz but in most locales, it includes a lot more). Also, as POSIX leaves it unspecified for locales other than the POSIX locales, how much those ranges are based on the collation order varies significantly between implementations.
- individual characters or collating elements (`x`, `[.dsz.]`)
- POSIX character classes `[:alpha:]`, `[:digit:]`
- equivalent classes like `[=e=]` for all the collating elements that have the same primary collating weight as `e` (could include things like  `é`)

So, for instance, `[acd[=e=]h-k[:digit:][.dzs.]]` matches on a collating element provided it's either `a`, `c`, `d`, `dzs` or is equivalent to `e` or collates between `h` and `k` or is classified as *digit*.

And if the specification starts with `^`, then it still matches one collating element, but with the set complemented. That is any collating element but the  ones specified.

So `[^a-z]` matches on any collating element that does not collate between `a` and `z`. For instance, it would probably match on `1` and `ẑ`, possibly on `X` or `DSZ` depending on the locale and the `grep` implementation, but not on `a`, `x` nor `z` and probably not on `é`.

So `grep '[^a-z]\{22\}'` matches on lines that *contain* a sequence of `22` collating elements that collate either before `a` or after `z`.

While `grep -v '[a-z]\{22\}'` matches on lines that do not contain a sequence of 22 collating elements collating between `a` and `z`.

Matching the same without `-v` is almost impossible to implement, you'd need to match on lines that contain no more than 21 `[a-z]` collating elements in between two `[^a-z]` element. But if the locale supports multi-character collating elements, that's not really possible. For instance, in those Hungarian locales, `[a-z]` matches on `dsz` but also on `d`, `s`, and `z` so you'll find that there, `[a-z]{0,21}` will match on `dszxxxyyyxxxyyyxxxyyyx` but also would `[a-z]{22}`.

For locales that don't have multi-character collating elements, you can do something like:

```
grep  '^[^a-z]*\([a-z]\{1,21\}[^a-z]\{1,\}\)*[a-z]\{0,21\}$'
```

Now, there are also some `grep` implementations that support more advanced regular syntaxes with options that have some *negation* operator.

For instance, the GNU or ast-open implementation of `grep` support perl-like (using libpcre in GNU grep, ast-open's own implementation for ast-open grep) regular expressions with the `-P` option which has a `(?!pattern)` *negative look-ahead operator*.

`(?!pattern)` matches with zero width at any point on the subject string provided the pattern doesn't match starting from there. So one could use:

```
 grep -P '^(?!.*[a-z]{22})'
```

to match on the start of the line provided it's not followed by any number of characters and 22 `[a-z]`s. Note however that in PCRE (not in ast-open), `[a-z]` only matches on abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz regardless of the locale.

ast-open also takes a `-X` option for what they call *augmented regexps*. Those augmented regex have a `!` operator that negates things. `x!` would match on anything other than `x` (including the empty string).

So with ast-open `grep`, you could also do:

```
grep -X '^(.*[a-z]{22}.*)!$'
```

Comment: Can you please shed some light for the use of **!** in RE which you earlier mentioned about.

Comment: @Neo_Returns, see edit.

Comment: Tanks for all your answers which give hours of work to understand 50%

Answer (score 3):

- `grep '[^a-z]\{22\}' /usr/share/dict/words`

  Looks for lines in the file `/usr/share/dict/words` which contain a string of 22 characters which are not lowercase letters. It is very likely that the file won't contain any such line. (Why would that file contain strings of 22 non-letters?)
- `grep -v '[a-z]\{22\}' /usr/share/dict/words`

  Looks for lines which do not contain strings of 22 letters. There will probably be very many such lines. (Because most words are shorter than 22 letters.)

Comment: can we use **!** and **^** alternatively

Comment: @Neo_Returns: `[^a-z]` matches one character which is not between `a` and `z` in the current locale collation sequence. You need 22 of those to match `[^a-z]\{22\}`. I don't understand what you mean by "use `!` and `^` alternatively".

Comment: I mean to say does [!a-z] and [^a-z] mean the same

Comment: @Neo_Returns: No they don't, at least on any grep that I have access to. Once upon a time they did mean the same inside `[`...`]`, but those times are long gone.

Comment: @AlexP, `[!...]` and `[^...]` mean the same in _shell pattern matching_... in most shells (including Debian's/Ubuntu's `dash`). Technically, the standard still only approves `[!...]` and leaves `[^...]` undefined, so if you look search wide enough, you might come across a shell that doesn't accept `[^...]`. But as far as I know, it's always been `[^...]` in _regular expressions_, which are what `grep` uses.